# Is following claim is right on meaning of word "daha" in verse 79:30

Tags: arabic, arabic-translation

In following [website](https://www.answering-christianity.com/egg-shaped_earth.htm#:%7E:text=for%20the%20meaning,results%20before%20him), the author claims that in Libyan, the word "daha" means egg or something like egg shape. In the Book "The Bible, the Quran and Sciences" by Maurice Bucaille, the following claim does not exist, in Maurice book either. I also tried to find daha in Libyan dialect, I failed there also
Is the claim right ?

Comment: As for the Libyan language this hardly looks like a strong proof and it is rather irrelevant to the meaning of words of the qur'an, as if that usage was known it would have been known by early Arabs and documented in tafsirs and dictionaries, which needs to be checked. Usually you may find old Arabic words used in a specific meaning which is in opposition to the modern usage in many local languages, but the dictionaries would cover this meaning.

Comment: Is there an good Libyan dictionary?